# Plotting graph from Text file using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, ns-3, ndnsim

I am using an NS3 based simulator called NDNsim. I can generate certain trace files that can be used to analyze performance, etc. However I need to visualize the data generated.

I am a complete Novice with R, and would like a way to visualize. Here is how the [output looks](https://gist.github.com/wuodland/9b2c76650ea37459f869c59d5f5f76ea) from which I would to plot. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What type of plot do you want? With that data so many can be produced...

Comment: @RuiBarradas Simple line plots like Time v/s InData (with others). There is one script I am using but would like a way to make separate graphs for the metrics. The current script I am using: https://github.com/cawka/ndnSIM-tutorial/blob/master/graphs/graph.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to know what you're looking for, since you have almost 50,000 measurements across 9 variables. Here's one way of getting a lot of that information on the screen:

```r
df <- read.table(paste0("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wuodland/",
                        "9b2c76650ea37459f869c59d5f5f76ea/raw/",
                        "6131919c105c95f8ba6967457663b9c37779756a/rate.txt"),
                 header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Kilobytes, color = Type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~FaceDescr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, somethings are making way more sense now with you using facet_wrap. I was using node in it instead of faceDescr like you posted. I think this is a good place for me to start and make the graphs better suited for my use.

Basically, I wanted to plot Kilobytes v/s Time graph for the different nodes(with line plots for the attributes). But it seems using facedescr makes more sense because facet_wrap with node. This is how I used to get on my own: https://i.imgur.com/FM3pnKh.png

edit:  it seems graphs generated depend on monitor resolution, looks better on higher res

Answer (score 1):

You could look into making sub structures from your input file and then graphing that by node, instead of trying to somehow invoke the plotter in just the right way.

```
df <- read.table(paste0("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wuodland/",
                        "9b2c76650ea37459f869c59d5f5f76ea/raw/",
                        "6131919c105c95f8ba6967457663b9c37779756a/rate.txt"),
                 header = TRUE)

smaller_df <- df[which(df$Type=='InData'), names(df) %in% c("Time", "Node", 
                 "FaceId", "FaceDescr", "Type", "Packets", "Kilobytes",
                 "PacketRaw", "KilobyteRaw")]

ggplot(smaller_df, aes(x = Time, y = Kilobytes, color = Type)) 
       + geom_line() 
       + facet_wrap (~ Node)
```

The above snippet makes a smaller data frame from your original text data using only the "InData" Type, and then plots that by nodes.